# Check whether a string contains a substring

Tags: string, perl, string-matching

How can I check whether a given string contains a certain substring, using Perl?

More specifically, I want to see whether `s1.domain.example` is present in the given string variable.

Answer (score 261, accepted):

To find out if a string contains substring you can use the [`index`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/index.html) function:

```
if (index($str, $substr) != -1) {
    print "$str contains $substr\n";
}
```

It will return the position of the first occurrence of `$substr` in `$str`, or -1 if the substring is not found.

Comment: This way is especially preferrable, when you are searching using a variable - this way you won't have to double-escape characters (in this variable string), that are special for regular expressions (like `:`).

Comment: See this as well - http://www.troubleshooters.com/codecorn/littperl/perlreg.htm

Answer (score 67):

Another possibility is to use [regular expressions](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) which is what Perl is famous for:

```
if ($mystring =~ /s1\.domain\.example/) {
   print qq("$mystring" contains "s1.domain.example"\n);
}
```

The backslashes are needed because a `.` can match any character. You can get around this by using the `\Q` and `\E` operators.

```
my $substring = "s1.domain.example";
    if ($mystring =~ /\Q$substring\E/) {
   print qq("$mystring" contains "$substring"\n);
}
```

Or, you can do as [eugene y](https://stackoverflow.com/users/244297/eugene-y) stated and use the [index](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/index.html) function.
Just a word of warning: Index returns a `-1` when it can't find a match instead of an `undef` or `0`.

Thus, this is an error:

```
my $substring = "s1.domain.example";
if (not index($mystring, $substr)) {
    print qq("$mystring" doesn't contains "$substring"\n";
}
```

This will be wrong if `s1.domain.example` is at the beginning of your string. I've personally been burned on this more than once.

Comment: I suppose `index()` is  faster than regexps in the simple case?

Comment: An attempted perl answer to a question about [removing substrings](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35593275/2019415) - I did not compare speed but `=~`, `index()`, `~~` and [`match::simple`](https://metacpan.org/pod/match::simple) all seemed a bit `awk`-ward ... :-\

Comment: You also have to make sure that the strings that you are comparing is not case sensitive. S1.DOMAIN.COM will not work for substring. But if you lc($givendomain), and then compare that with "s1.domain.com", then that will work. Also, substring is not necessarily the right approach - see my note above to eugene y's response

Comment: @David W. Somehow I can't get `domain.com` to match `subdomain.domain.com` using the REGEX above, any ideas ?

Answer (score 16):

**Case Insensitive Substring Example**

This is an extension of Eugene's answer, which converts the strings to lower case before checking for the substring:

```
if (index(lc($str), lc($substr)) != -1) {
    print "$str contains $substr\n";
}
```

Comment: Note that [`fc`](https://perldoc.pl/functions/fc) is recommended over `lc` for case-insensitive comparisons.