# How to check if a path is a subpath of an other in perl?

Tags: perl, filesystems

there are some answers to this problem in other languages. I'm new to perl and I'm doing this (is more comparing strings than using filesystem-functions):

```
use File::Spec;

sub has_common_prefix {
  my ($path, $subpath) = @_;
  $path = uc (File::Spec->canonpath($path))."\\";
  $subpath = uc (File::Spec->canonpath($subpath));

  if ( substr($subpath, 0, length($path)) eq $path ) return 1;
  return 0;
};

has_common_prefix('c:\\/abCD/EFgh', 'C:\abcd\\efgh/ijk.txt');
```

I want to know if there are better ways to do this, well more "perlisch" :-)

Thanks.

Comment: You can also check if a string `$x` has a prefix `$y`, using `$x =~ /^\Q$y/`

Comment: The [`index`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/index.html) function might be handy also.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7283274/check-whether-a-string-contains-a-substring

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I've hacked this, but I'm not very proud of it and I hope someone comes up with something better. I've searched the CPAN but am surprised to have found nothing relevant

My idea was to use the `abs2rel` function from [`File::Spec::Functions`](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Spec::Functions). That's fine, except that it tries too hard for this purpose and will return `../..` for `abs2rel('/usr', '/usr/a/b')`. It will also return the first value unchanged on systems that use volumes in the path

This just wraps `abs2rel` inside a function `is_within` which rejects both of those cases, but otherwise returns the relative path (a true value) intact. That means that `is within('/usr', '/usr')` will return `.`, which is true, but you can test it for that specific case if you think a directory shouldn't contain itself

***Note*** that this doesn't check whether the paths are to directories, nor does it check whether the paths even exist

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use File::Spec::Functions qw/ abs2rel  file_name_is_absolute  updir /;

my @pairs = (
    [qw{ /usr      /usr/bin } ],
    [qw{ /usr/etc  /usr/bin } ],
    [qw{ /var      /usr/bin } ],
    [qw{ /usr/bin  /usr/bin } ],
);

for ( @pairs ) {
    my ($path, $subpath) = @$_;
    my $within = is_within($subpath, $path);
    printf qq{"%s" is %swithin "%s"  (%s)\n},
            $subpath,
            ($within ? '' : 'not '),
            $path,
            $within // 'undef';
}


sub is_within {
    my ($path, $container) = @_;

    my $a2r = abs2rel($path, $container);

    return if file_name_is_absolute($a2r) or index($a2r, updir) == 0;

    $a2r;
}
```

#### output

```
"/usr/bin" is within "/usr"  (bin)
"/usr/bin" is not within "/usr/etc"  (undef)
"/usr/bin" is not within "/var"  (undef)
"/usr/bin" is within "/usr/bin"  (.)
```

Answer (score 0):

File::Spec and its replacement Path::Class don't touch the file system, so they don't handle case differences, and they don't down handle short vs long forms.

```
use Path::Class qw( dir file );
use Win32       qw( );

sub subsumes {
   my $dir  = dir(Win32::GetLongPathName($_[0]));
   my $file = file(Win32::GetLongPathName($_[1]));
   return $dir->subsumes($file);
}
```