# search a specific sub string pattern in a string using perl

Tags: string, perl, search, perl-module

I'm a newbie to perl, I went through this [Check whether a string contains a substring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7283274/check-whether-a-string-contains-a-substring) to how to check a substring is present in a string, Now my scenario is little different

I have a string like

`/home/me/Desktop/MyWork/systemfile/directory/systemfile64.elf` ,

In the end this might be `systemfile32.elf` or `systemfile16.elf`,so In my perl script I need to check whether this string contains a a substring in the format systemfile*.elf.
How can I achieve this in perl ?

I'm planing to do like this

```
if(index($mainstring, _serach_for_pattern_systemfile*.elf_ ) ~= -1) {
    say" Found the string";
}
```

Comment: `$string =~ /systemfile.*\.elf/` and you should check out http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html

Comment: Yea that solved It, thanks

Comment: can you post it as answer, so that i can put correct answer

Comment: There you go, posted

Comment: and what if a file exist called 64bitsystemfile.elfde? you will still get a match for systemfile and .elf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the pattermatching

```
if ($string =~ /systemfile\d\d\.elf$/){
   # DoSomething
}
```

`\d` stands for a digit (0-9)

`$` stands for end of string

Comment: @HariprasadCR: The index function searches for one string within another, but **without** the wildcard-like behavior of a full regular-expression pattern match

Comment: @HariprasadCR So for me it sounds like you have to do two separate checks if you want to use `index`

Answer (score 1):

Well

```
if( $mainstring =~ m'/systemfile(16|32)\.elf$' ) {
   say" Found the string";
}
```

does the job.

---

For your informations :

```
$string =~ m' ... '
```

is the same than

```
$string =~ / ... /
```

which checks the string against the given regular expression. This is one of the most useful features of the Perl language.

More info at http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html

(I did use the m'' syntax to improve readability, because of the presence of another '/' character in the regexp. I could also write `/\/systemfile\d+\.elf$/`

Comment: I agree with using an explicit `m` on the match operator so that you can change the delimiter. But I think that the single quote is a terrible choice of alternative. It makes the regex look like a string. I would have probably gone with `m[systemfile(16|32)\.elf$]`.

Answer (score 0):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $string = 'systemfile16.elf';
if ($string =~ /^systemfile.*\.elf$/) {
print "Found string $string";
  } else {
print "String not found";
```

will match systemfile'anythinghere'.elf if you have a set directory.

if you want to search entire string, including directory then:

```
my $string = 'c:\\windows\\system\\systemfile16.elf';
if ($string =~ /systemfile.*\.elf$/) {
print "Found string $string";
  } else {
print "String not found";
```

if you only want to match 2 systemfile then 2 numeric characters .elf then use the other methods mentioned above by other answers. but if you want systemanything.elf then use one of these.

Comment: You should escape the last dot, because it is the character dot not the placeholder

Comment: @Jens. true, I never tested the code. Will update it, although it will work regardless of it being wrong :) so by not escaping the . it will accept systemfile00.self as a match as well, here we want to match exactly .elf only. Thanks for spotting it

Comment: Actually, "systemfile.." is at the end of the string, so you don't want that `^` at the start (and you example string should rather be `'/home/me/Desktop/MyWork/systemfile/directory/systemfile09.elf'` for instance). Moreover, `.*` will match anything including strings like `systemfile/not/the/right/one/.elf` ... So definitely not what the OP would like.

Comment: ok, I missed the part where he wanted the entire string, so we should then drop the ^. However he specifies "substring in the format systemfile*.elf" which means systemfile"anythinghere".elf so could be systemfile16.elf, systemfile32.elf or sytemfile64bit.elf in my view.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($string =~ /systemfile.*\.elf/) {
    # Do something with the string.
}
```

That should match only the strings you seek (given that every time, a given string is stored in `$string`). Inside the curly brackets you should write your logic.

The `.` stands for "any character" and the `*` stands for "as many times you see the last character". So, `.*` means "any character as many times you see it". If you know that the string will end in this pattern, then it will be safer to add `$` at the end of the pattern to mark that the string should end with this:

```
$string =~ /systemfile.*\.elf$/
```

Just don't forget to `chomp $string` to avoid any line-breaks that might mess with your desired output.

Comment: This will also match `*systemfile*.elf*` the OP specifically says he wants to match systemfile*.elf hence why I answered `if ($string =~ /^systemfile.*.\.elf$/);`

Comment: and I made the same mistake by assuming he wanted to match the filename only without path. :)

Comment: this will match strings with the full path as well